# How to write contents of data frame back to range?

Tags: r, excel, bert-toolkit

I need to perform the following sequence:

1. Open Excel Workbook
2. Read specific worksheet into R dataframe
3. Read from a database updating dataframe
4. Write dataframe back to worksheet

I have steps 1-3 working OK using the BERT tool. (the R scripting interface)
For step 2 I use `range.to.data.frame` from BERT

Any pointer on how to perform step 4? There is no `data.frame.to.range`
I tried `range$put_Value(df)` but no error return and no update to Excel
I can update a single cell from R using `put_Value` - which I cannot see documented

```
#
# manipulate status data using R BERT tool
#

wb <- EXCEL$Application$get_ActiveWorkbook()
wbname = wb$get_FullName()

ws <- EXCEL$Application$get_ActiveSheet()
topleft = ws$get_Range( "a1" )
rng = topleft$get_CurrentRegion()

#rngbody = rng$get_Offset(1,0)

ssot = rng$get_Value()

ssotdf = range.to.data.frame( ssot, headers=T )
# emulate data update on 2 columns
ssotdf$ServerStatus = "Disposed"
ssotdf$ServerID = -1

# try to write df back
retcode = rng$put_Value(ssotdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't use R Excel BERT.
Try the `openxlsx` library. You probably can do all the steps using that library. For the step 4, after installing openxlsx library, the following code will write a file:

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(ssotdf, 'Dataframe.xlsx',asTable = T)
```

Comment: That is very helpful. Thank you. In addition to the simple read/write Excel, openxls seems to have the ability to manipulate columns etc. ideally i would like to be able to call my R code from VBA - like you can with BERT. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not changing the size of the range, so you are not going to see your new columns. Try creating a new range that has two extra columns before you insert the data.

Comment: Good analysis - but the 2 columns referenced in the source code already existed in the Excel sheet (which you couldn't have known)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same question and was able to resolve it by transforming the `data.frame` to a matrix in the call to `put_value`.  I figured this out after playing with the old version in `excel-functions.r`.  Try something like:

```
retcode = rng$put_Value(as.matrix(ssotdf))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have already solved your problem but, if not, the following stripped down R function does what I think you need:

```
testDF <- function(rng1,rng2){
  app <- EXCEL$Application
  ref1 <- app$get_Range( rng1 ) # get source range reference
  data <- ref1$get_Value()      # get source range data
  #
  ref2 <- app$get_Range( rng2 ) # get destination range reference
  ref2$put_Value( data )        # put data in destination range
}
```

I simulated a dataframe by setting values in range `"D4:F6"` of the speadsheet to:

```
col1    col2    col3
 1       2      txt1
 7       3      txt2
```

then ran

```
testDF("D4:F6","H10:J12")
```

in the Bert console. The dataframe then appears in range `"H10:J12"`.

Comment: is it possible to print the R output in Excel without knowing the dimensions of the resultant output from R beforehand?